# getAssets() not recognised in different class other than MainActivity.class

Tags: android

I'm not able to put the custom font through Typeface, as getAssets() is not showing up while writing createFromAsset. 
I've used getContext(), getActivity(), placed the assets in the project and not in src, all not finding soln.
Please tell me the error.

```
package com.example.shubhojit.careersafter10th.ViewHolder;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.shubhojit.careersafter10th.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.example.shubhojit.careersafter10th.R;

public class Courses_After10thViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView txtCourseName;
    public ImageView courseImage;
    public TextView txtCourseDuration;
    Typeface courseName;
    Typeface courseDuration;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public Courses_After10thViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtCourseName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.courses_after10th_name);
        courseImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.courses_after10th_image);
        txtCourseDuration = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.courses_after10th_duration);

        courseName = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"Fonts/Antipasto-RegularTrial.ttf");

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't see what is the `context` in your code. Do you pass the context to your class correctly?

Comment: @RickyMo there's no need to pass the context, one probably cannot even pass it into there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to crate assets under `Fonts` folder then place `Antipasto-RegularTrial.ttf`:

```
courseName = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"Fonts/Antipasto-RegularTrial.ttf");
txtCourseName.setTypeface(courseName);
```

Comment: this does not solve the problem, that the `context` is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

within the scope of a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, you can obtain a handle to the `Context` alike shown in below code (it also considers `View.isInEditMode()`, to make the XML preview work):

```
/* obtain a handle to the parent RecyclerView */
this.mRecyclerView = (SomeRecyclerView) viewHolder.getParent();

/* obtain a handle to the it's Context */
Context context;
if(viewHolder.isInEditMode()) {context = ((ContextThemeWrapper) this.mRecyclerView.getContext()).getBaseContext();}
else  {context = this.mRecyclerView.getContext();}
```

most likely, `Fonts/Antipasto-RegularTrial.ttf` should be renamed to `fonts/antipasto_regulartrial.ttf`, in order to be a *valid* resource descriptor. this may vary in between assets and resources; see [Fonts in XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml) - this explains how this can be done meanwhile.